# JavaFX: Binding the size of a SubScene to it's parent

Tags: properties, javafx, scene

I have a tabpane with a tab inside. The content of the tab is created by calling this method:

```
private Node populateModelTab()
{
    BorderPane modelTabContent = new BorderPane();
    VBox subSceneRoot = new Vbox();
    subScene = new SubScene(subSceneRoot, subSceneWidth, subSceneHeight);
    modelTabContent.setCenter(subScene);
    return modelTabContent;
}
```

Now instead of using fixed values for the subscene's width and height, I would like to bind them to the maximum size that the actual tab has.

I tried to bind the dimensions to the surrounding boderpane, which didn't work for me. Also, I tried to put some stuff (like a rectangle) inside the VBox. I only get something displayed on that tab, when I set the actual values for the subscene's dimensions.

Maybe someone knows how to make it behave the way I want to.

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467440/place-meshview-in-scene)

Comment: Wow, thank's a bunch! :)